# JavaFX Scrollpane with dynamic GridPane

Tags: java, javafx, scrollpane

I have a program which has a `BorderPane` as main container. In the center of this `BorderPane` is a `ScrollPane` which contains a dynamic `GridPane`.

I want to be able to display large GridPanes with more rows, so I wrapped the `GridPane` in a `ScrollPane`. (I used the Scene Builder)

The scrollbars don't work. I tried changing the `HMax` and `VMax` attribute, but nothing happens when scrolling up or down.

Next I tried to reset the content with `myScrollPane.setContent(myDynamicGridpane)` after generating a new dynamic GridPane.

I would like to view my complete dynamic GridPane by scrolling up and down.

The FXML section generated by the Scene Builder:

```
<ScrollPane fx:id="contentScrollPane" fitToHeight="true" fitToWidth="true" hbarPolicy="ALWAYS" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" nodeOrientation="LEFT_TO_RIGHT" prefHeight="291.0" prefWidth="422.0" vbarPolicy="ALWAYS" BorderPane.alignment="TOP_LEFT">
     <content>
        <GridPane fx:id="dynamicPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="126.0" prefWidth="277.0">
          <columnConstraints>
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="150.0" minWidth="150.0" prefWidth="150.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="100.0" minWidth="100.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
          </columnConstraints>
          <rowConstraints>
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          </rowConstraints>
           <padding>
              <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0" />
           </padding>
        </GridPane>
     </content>
  </ScrollPane>
```

[image: ScrollPane]

Comment: Is there any reason you're hard-coding the min/pref/max sizes of the rows and columns, and the grid pane itself? In particular, since you've hardcoded the pref width and height of the grid pane, it probably won't resize when you add additional controls to it. What happens if you remove those?

Comment: Thank you! It seems like you were right, the GridPane didn't resize. When using the default USE_COMPUTED_SIZE on the GridPane, the ScrollPane works.